# Substracting area from Rectangle with Polygon in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Basically, I have an image (rectangle) and a polygon coordinates within it. I want to paint the outside of the polygon area.

```
vrx = np.array(([20,80],[60,50],[100.80],[80,120],[40,120]), np.int32)
img = cv2.fillPoly(img, [vrx], 255)
```

This code fills the color (white) with in Polygon, I need the inverse part of it. I want to mask white color for that image except the polygon part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912928/fill-the-outside-of-contours-opencv/37914138

Comment: Thanks, it works fine