# Fill outside of contour with white OpenCv Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find the contour with the largest area and fill the outside of the contour with white. I have looked at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912928/fill-the-outside-of-contours-opencv)
The solution works well when using many contours but when I try to use it with one contour it only shows the contour with the inside and outside black. I am trying to rather create a mask that only leaves the interior area of the contour. I am using `max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)` to get the largest contour. Using OpenCv, Python

Comment: Why not just invert the mask, so the inside of the contour is black and the outside is white. Draw your white filled contour on a black background image with fillPoly() and invert or simpler draw a black filled contour on a white background image. Please always show **your** code. Please read this forum's help section about how to ask a good question and providing minimally reproducible and verifiable code. Note that findContours() allows you to get only the outside contour.

Comment: Do you have any sample images you can add to the post?